# Testing Neo4j unmanaged extensions

Tags: neo4j

Much of our application functionality is exposed via a Neo4j unmanaged extension. Currently, to test this functionality (in as realistic a way possible) we use the `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper` class to start a server programmatically, just as other extensions such as the [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension/blob/1.9/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/extension/auth/TestAuthentification.java#L70) do.

The `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper` class is now deprecated, however, and there [doesn't appear to be a replacement](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/1106). So assuming unmanaged extensions aren't going away at some point (and I hope they're not) what's the best way to test them? Is something like the Jersey test framework the recommended approach?

Comment: Maybe [this blog](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-testing-unmanaged) by Mark Needham could be helpful?

Comment: @jjaderberg This was exactly the pointer I needed (don't how I missed it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a big props to [jjaderberg's pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233577/testing-neo4j-unmanaged-extensions/22235030?noredirect=1#comment33763269_22233577) and [Mark Needham's blog](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-testing-unmanaged), it seems what was needed was the `ServerBuilder`, used ala:

```
CommunityNeoServer server = CommunityServerBuilder
    .server()
    .onPort(7575)
    .withThirdPartyJaxRsPackage("my.resource.package", "/endpoint")
    .build();
server.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I knew I'd written about it somewhere but couldn't find it! :P

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at a project of mine: https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-spock-extension
It provides some extensions to [Spock](http://www.spockframework.org) to make testing unmanaged extension easy.

For an example of a black box test, see [SampleNeo4jServerSpec](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-spock-extension/blob/master/src/test/groovy/org/neo4j/extension/spock/SampleNeo4jServerSpec.groovy). This spawns a neo4j server with a unmanaged extension and fires REST requests for testing.

The other type of test is a white box test, see [SampleNeo4jSpec](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-spock-extension/blob/master/src/test/groovy/org/neo4j/extension/spock/SampleNeo4jSpec.groovy). This just instantiates the unmanaged extension and calls the methods there directly.

I will publish a more verbose blog post on neo4j-spock-extension next weeks.

Comment: Thanks Stefan this looks really interesting. I'm going to add a quickie answer for my immediate problem but I'll definitely check your work out closely since we're much in need of a better general way of testing a REST service.

Comment: feedback on neo4j-spock-extension is highly appreciated :-)